# Remove HTML Tags which are place in same sequence or one after another

Tags: c#

I have following string:

```
Result = "<em>Administration</em> <em>Resources</em> Officer <em>paragraphs</em>";
```

Can any one guide me how to generate following string with the replacement of above string:

```
Result = "<em>Administration Resources</em> Officer <em>paragraphs</em> "
```

Basically I have multiple "Emphasized text" tag in string I want to remove which are place one word to another word and generate one "Emphasized text" tag of that two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (result.Contains(" <em>")) {
    result = result.Replace(" <em>", "<em>");
}
result = result.Replace("</em><em>", "");
```

Comment: This will mangle the string and will fail the test that I posted in my answer, but if that does not matter, it's by far the simplest approach :)

Comment: @jimmy I can't see why it would mangle the string, the WHILE removes leading space in front of <em> and the last line removes unneeded pairs. Admitedly not pretty, but it works. What are you alluding to?

Comment: Try to run it in a unit test where the space in between should not be removed.  This implementation will remove the space between the two em tags Administration</em>[space]<em>Resource and will produce AdministrationResource instead of Administration Resource (with the space in between still).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a state machine approach using switch statement that will do what you want:

```
public class TagCleaner
{
    public string CleanEM(string input)
    {
        var beginTag = "<em>";
        var endTag = "</em>";

        var parsable = input;
        var state = 0;
        var output = string.Empty;
        var done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case 0:  // new attempt... find <em>
                    {
                        var idx = parsable.IndexOf(beginTag);

                        if (idx < 0)
                        {
                            output = parsable;
                            state = -1;
                        }

                        if (idx > 0)
                        {
                            output = parsable.Substring(0, idx + beginTag.Length);
                        }

                        if (idx == 0)
                        {
                            output = beginTag;
                        }

                        parsable = parsable.Substring(idx + beginTag.Length); //chopped off anything before the <em> tag for next round
                        state = 1; // set state to go find matching </em>                        
                    }
                    break;

                case 1: // found <em>, now find matching </em>
                    {
                        var idx = parsable.IndexOf(endTag);

                        if (idx < 0)
                        {
                            output += parsable;
                            state = -1;
                        }

                        if (idx > 0)
                        {
                            output += parsable.Substring(0, idx + endTag.Length);
                        }

                        if (idx == 0) //<em></em>... remove the last <em> tag from output...
                        {
                            output = output.Substring(0, output.LastIndexOf(beginTag));
                        }

                        parsable = parsable.Substring(idx + endTag.Length); //chopped off anything before the </em> tag for next round

                        if (parsable.Length < 1)
                            state = -1; //done
                        else
                            state = 2; // set state to find the next <em>
                    }
                    break;

                case 2: //just found </em>, now look for the next <em>
                    {
                        var idx = parsable.IndexOf(beginTag);

                        if (idx < 0)
                        {
                            output += parsable;
                            state = -1; //done
                        }

                        if (idx >= 0)
                        {
                            var prefix = parsable.Substring(0, idx);
                            var re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^ *$");
                            if (re.IsMatch(prefix)) // found 0 or more spaces between the </em> and <em> tag... 
                            {
                                output = output.Substring(0, output.LastIndexOf(endTag)); //chop off the last </em> from output
                                output += prefix; //add the spaces to the output
                                parsable = parsable.Substring(idx + beginTag.Length);
                                state = 1; //set state to go find </em>
                            }
                            else // there are other things beside empty spaces in between...
                            {
                                output += parsable.Substring(0, idx + beginTag.Length);
                                parsable = parsable.Substring(idx + beginTag.Length);
                                state = 1; //set state to go find </em>
                            }
                        }

                        if (parsable.Length < 1)
                            state = -1; //done
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    done = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

It'll do what you want and with a bit of changes, you can switch it to clean whatever tag you want.

Here is a sample MS Test to prove that it work...

```
[TestClass]
public class TagCleanerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Clean_EM_Tag_That_Are_In_Sequence_Even_With_Spaces_In_Between()
    {
        var input = "<em>Administration</em> <em>Resource</em> Officer <em>paragraphs</em>";
        var expected = "<em>Administration Resource</em> Officer <em>paragraphs</em>";
        var sut = new TagCleaner();

        var actual = sut.CleanEM(input);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```